# Jenkins API URL clashes with a module named "api"

Tags: python, django, jenkins

I have a Django project set up with Jenkins. One of my apps has the literal name `api`. When I go to view the coverage report for this app, I am taken to a URL with the suffix `/cobertura/api/`. Because this URL ends with the string `api`, Jenkins interprets this as API access to the URL `/cobertura/` instead of the `api` page of the coverage report.

How can I deal with this? I don't use the Jenkins API at all, so disabling it entirely would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: think about renaming your app to `api_`

Comment: Or anything other than `api`.

Comment: What app do you use to add Jenkins support to your project?

Comment: I use [django-jenkins](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins). Renaming the app would have far-reaching implications, so the best solution I can think of is writing a script to rewrite api to api_ in coverage.xml after it is generated but before Jenkins sees it. If nothing better comes up I'll write it up and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added the following to the end of my Jenkins build script:

```
cp reports/coverage.xml reports/coverage2.xml
sed 's/ name=\"api\"/ name=\"api_\"/' reports/coverage2.xml > reports/coverage.xml
```

This rewrites the coverage report before Jenkins processes it, changing the `api` name to `api_`. Since only the `name` XML attribute is affected and not `filename`, the coverage report itself works normally.

Comment: Old thread, but ran into this today on my windows jenkins instance.  Here is the powershell command I used in case it helps others.    powershell -Command "(gc 'coverage.xml') -replace 'name=\"api\"','name=\"api_\"' | Out-File 'test_file.txt' -encoding utf8"